# [Tensorflow]Different Graph architecture in COCO pre-trained model and re-train model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have followed the doc:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md
to retrained the model of ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz.
 I only modify the pipe config with 
- finetune to TRUE 
- set the model path
- set the trained data path with actual path of tfrecord

then, I try to use the export script with :
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md
Finally I have got the pb with my own data.

but I found that the result of re-train model was not the same architecture with the one in ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz

Here is the picture which I captured from Tensorboard:

- The retrained one of my own data and pipe configure .
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kegcT.jpg
- The original one from pb file within ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAGi3.jpg

According to the pictures from tensorboard , I found that there were two input tensors in BoxPredictor but there were three with original.

Could anyone who could help me to solve this problem ?
Thanks...

PS: I use the tensorflow with version 1.4.0-GPU

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue? I have a similar one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49633273/mobilenet-ssd-architecture-downloaded-vs-trained